# Hiding an element through DOM traversal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function

What if it has few parents? (as in grandparents, great grandparents)

```
<div class="lvl1">
    <div class="lvl1.1">
        <div class="lvl1.2">
            <button class="btn-submit">Click Me</button>
            <div class="a1">Hello
        <div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="lvl2">
    <div class="b1">
         <div class="b2">Make me disappear!</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="lvl3">
    <div class="c1">Thank you.
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
    $(function(){
        $(".btn-submit").click(function() {   
           $(this).parent(".lvl1").siblings(".lvl2").children(".b2").hide();
        });
    });
```

How to use .parent, .parents, .siblings, .children, .next, .prev to show and hide the div?

Comment: Use `find()`, not `children()`

Comment: actually I just want to know how to use these methods (.parent, .siblings etc.). Any example?

Comment: The jQuery documentation reveals all: http://api.jquery.com

Comment: As an alternative: **don't.**   Use specific classes and/or data attibutes to match buttons with content.  Using parents/siblings/children etc makes your html too static and any change (eg adding another wrapper div or moving the order) will break your code in a hard-to-find-what's-wrong manner.

Answer (score 2):

If I assume that you have that structure repeated and want to remove the one in the same copy as the `.btn_submit` that was clicked, we go up to the `.lvl1` via `closest`, over to the `.lvl2` via `.nextAll().first()` (or we could just use `.next)`, and then `.find` the `.b2` in there:

```
$(".btn-submit").click(function() {
    $(this).closest(".lvl1").nextAll(".lvl2").first().find(".b2").hide();
});
```

Your code is very close, just two things that I had to change:

- Instead of using `.siblings(".lvl2")`, which will find all of them, I used `.nextAll(".lvl2").first()` to just find the one immediately after "this" `.lvl1`.
- I used `find` instead of `children`, because `children` will only go down one level (direct child), not search descendants

I also used `closest(".lvl1")` so that if you move the `.btn_submit` deeper into `.lvl1`, it will continue working.

Live Example:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".btn-submit").click(function() {
    $(this)
    .closest(".lvl1")
    .nextAll(".lvl2")
    .first()
    .find(".b2")
    .hide();
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="lvl1">
  <button class="btn-submit">Click Me</button>
  <div class="a1">Hello
  </div>
</div>

<div class="lvl2">
  <div class="b1">
    <div class="b2">Make me disappear!</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="lvl3">
  <div class="c1">Thank you.
  </div>
</div>

<div class="lvl1">
  <button class="btn-submit">Click Me</button>
  <div class="a1">Hello
  </div>
</div>

<div class="lvl2">
  <div class="b1">
    <div class="b2">Make me disappear!</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="lvl3">
  <div class="c1">Thank you.
  </div>
</div>

<div class="lvl1">
  <button class="btn-submit">Click Me</button>
  <div class="a1">Hello
  </div>
</div>

<div class="lvl2">
  <div class="b1">
    <div class="b2">Make me disappear!</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="lvl3">
  <div class="c1">Thank you.
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: what if the btn-submit has grandparent and great grandparent?

Comment: @Bexie: `closest` stops at the nearest one. (It also, technically, starts with the element itself, so if `.btn-submit` were *also* a `.lvl1`, we'd need `parents(".lvl1").first()` or `parent().closest(".lvl1")` instead. But it isn't, so we can just use the simple one.)

Answer (score 0):

there is possible to disappear div directly using,

```
$(".b2").hide();
```

but if you want to use ".parent, .parents, .siblings, .children, .next, .prev",

```
$(".btn-submit").parent().siblings(".lvl2").children().children(".b2").hide();
```

need to you children() Two times... because .b2 is not directly child to .lvl2,

another best way to hide ".b2" is,

```
$(".btn-submit").parent().siblings(".lvl2").find(".b2").hide();
```

so your Ans is:

```
 $(".btn-submit").click(function() { 
           $(".btn-submit").parent().siblings(".lvl2").find(".b2").hide(); 
 });
```

Comment: what if the btn-submit has grandparent and great grandparent?

Comment: This will hide **all** of the `.b2`s, not just the one related to the structure of the specific `.btn-submit` that was clicked.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder,    A good point & your answer works with all scenario.  thanks for increase my way of thinking ...

Answer (score -1):

`.children` selects the *children* and not *descendants* of the element. You just need to replace the `.children` with the `.find` method and your code will select the target element.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? Its the right answer: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/dw77k0px/

Comment: Thank you @RoryMcCrossan :) what if it has few parents?

Comment: I didn't downvote and see no good reason for doing so. One thing, though: If we assume the structure is repeated, this isn't the only problem. `siblings(".lvl2")` will match all of the sibling `.lvl2` elements, and so we end up hiding all of their `.b2`s.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thanks for creating a fiddle.

Comment: @Vohuman no problem, was about to post it as an answer but you beat me to it :)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder A good point, and your answer is more comprehensive. However this does solve the immediate problem with the OPs sample. Downvoters gonna downvote I guess.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: Tell it. :-) Totally unjustified in this case in my view. Geez, people.